# Ответ сервера на C#

Tags: c#

Как просмотреть что написано на странице на C#?

Например содержание страницы содержит команду для программы:

**wait**

**check**

**etc...**

ну и

```
if(содержание == "wait")
{
    wait(true);
}
```

и ещё, как разбить строку, вот на php это explode(), а на шарпе как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нашел ответ сам, может кому нужен будет

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

          WebClient wc = new WebClient();
          string remoteUri = "http://";
          byte[] myDataBuffer = wc.DownloadData (remoteUri);
          string download = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myDataBuffer);
          Console.WriteLine(download);
          Console.Read();

        }
    }
```